# How to jitclass the following simple thread

Tags: python, numba

I have the following thread class and a simple (Axis) class which is part of the platform. I want to jitclass both classes, but any of my tries failed.

```
class Axis(object):
    """
    :param config: configuration file
    :type config: ConfigParser
    """

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

class Platform(threading.Thread):
    """
    :param config: configuration file
    :type config: ConfigParser
    :param platformType: type of platform
    :type platformType: int
    """

    def __init__(self, config, platformType):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = False
        self.platformType = platformType
        self.trace = False
        self.lock = threading.Event()
        self.syncLock = threading.Lock()
        self.axis = Axis(config)
```

Anyone with an idea or reference?

Answer (score 1):

You can only jit-compile classes with `numba` data types as attributes.
For example this works:

```
from numba import jitclass, float64

axisspec = [('x', float64), ('y', float64)]

@jitclass(axisspec)
class Axis(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Numba is good for number crunching, not working with general Python objects.
Your case looks more like an application of PyPy.